# name 'Child1' is not defined

Tags: python

I am very new to python programming I have a code thats shows the below error

```
child_=Child1()
NameError: name 'Child1' is not defined
```

Here is the code that i have written in pycharm project

Parent1.py

```
class Parent1:
    value1="this is value1"
    value2="this is value2"
class Parent2:
    value3="this is value1"
    value4="this is value2"
class Child1(Parent1,Parent2):

    child_=Child1()
    print(child_.value1)
    print(child_.value2)
    print(child_.value3)
    print(child_.value4)
```

I have defined def before class of Child1 but still I couldn't able to solve the issue.

Comment: why are you trying to create an object for a class within the class itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot initialize a static class variable which references the class itself.

```
class Parent1:
    value1="this is value1"
    value2="this is value2"

class Parent2:
    value3="this is value1"
    value4="this is value2"

class Child1(Parent1,Parent2):
    pass

child_=Child1()
print(child_.value1)
print(child_.value2)
print(child_.value3)
print(child_.value4)
```

Comment: Please include some context. Code dumps are not valid answers.

Comment: can u elaborate a bit? why should we need to include some context

Comment: You've elaborately disguised the fact that this is an indentation typo on OP's part.

Comment: That's according to the rules as defined in the help center. If nobody explains what they fixed or what was wrong in the first place, questions become useless.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Don't forget to mention the pass instruction. So, no, it was not a typo.